# Get specific value from datatable with where-clause

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, where-clause, datarow

I want to `query` a specific value from a `DataTable`.

Lets say i have a `DataTable` which contains 2 columns:

- id
- item_name

Now what I want to do is like i would do it with mysql: `SELECT * FROM "DataTable" WHERE item_name = 'MyItemName'`

And then get the id that belongs to that 'item_name'...

```
int blah;
while (MyReader.Read())
{
    blah = MyReader.GetInt32("id");
}
```

**Now: how can I do this using `DataTable`?**

I've got a snippet but I can't seem to show the returned value in a messagebox:

```
string test = Item1txt.Text;

var query = producten.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x.Field<string>("item_name") == test);
foreach (var st in query)
{
    MessageBox.Show(st.ToString());
    // how can i show the id that belongs to "test" ?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`query` will be an `IQueryable<DataRow>`, so `st` will be a `DataRow`. Try this:

```
foreach (var st in query)
{
    MessageBox.Show(st.Field<int>("id").ToString());
}
```

Or if you know there will only item with that `item_name`, here's an alternative version which does essentially the same thing, but is probably a bit easier to understand:

```
var st = producten.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field<string>("item_name") == test);
if(item != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(st.Field<int>("id").ToString());
}
```

Comment: +1 this is what i was looking for. I thought there was something wrong with my `linq` query but it's not :D thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq directly on the datatable without the need of `Rows` or the `Cast`.

```
var query = producten.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("item_name") == test);
foreach (var st in query)
{
    MessageBox.Show(st.Field<int>("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the Rowfilter property of the defaultview of the datatable, but I must admit I never did LINQ myself, so there's probably a better way now...